# How to make my UICollectionViewCell responsive so it fits on iphone 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a CollectionView with 6 cells each row having two cells
and I made my cells 160x160, it works well from iPhone 6 and up but when I try it on iPhone 5 the cells break, I tried it with vary of traits but it didn't work for me so far. I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction. Unfortunately I don't have the code because I am not at work but if needed I can upload it tomorrow.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question than i think you need to override this method in your class you can add check according to device

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return CGSizeMake(widthDependOniPhoneScreenSIze, HeighDependOniPhoneScreenSIze);
```

}

> Instead of using 160x160 use custom height width of cell according to screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Total width of iPhone 5 is 320 point. That means if you want to use cell size as 160 * 160 then you have to either remove spacing between cell and also taking full screen width (because 160 + 160 = 320) or you have to decrease the horizontal width less than 160